# Unable to attach database in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I clicked on the "Attach.." button under databases, this error shows up:

[image]

Comment: Sounds like SSMS problem. What version are you using?

Comment: seems duplicate of [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42562/attaching-a-database-in-ssms-gives-error) which is already marked as answered.

Comment: I agree with the others. I've recommend use the latest version of SSMS. That looks like SSMS 2008 or SSMS 2012. SSMS 2017 (V17.6) is the latest version and supports SQL Server 2008+.